# Passing AVPlayer reference from a cell to a view controller freezes video but audio continues

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an `AVPlayer` subclass inside a `UICollectionViewCell`. I have a button that when I press it, should display that same video in full screen mode. What I thought I could do is present a `UIViewController` and pass it the reference to the `AVPlayer` so that it can add it as a subview and continue playing. However, what happens is it adds it as a subview, the video pauses, but the audio carries on playing. Why? How can I solve this?

Comment: is your issue resolved? as I am also getting same issue

Comment: @Van Yeah, I forgot to mark my answer as solved, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if you pass an `AVPlayer` to another view controller, you have to remove the original strong reference to it. You can only have one reference to the `AVPlayer` otherwise it starts freezing and going weird.

Comment: even after removing refernece from cell its freezing.. I Have added player in avplayerlayer in table cell and when passing to player controller i am setting cell.player = nil. Can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Use AVPlayerController to do this. Whenever you click on button, just present the AVPlayerController with the same instance.

```
    @IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: Any) {
      let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"FullScreenPlayer") as! FullScreenPlayerViewController
      vc.player = playerInCell
      present(vc, animated: false)
}
```

**Note: FullScreenPlayerController is subclass of AVPlayerViewController**

Comment: This is essentially what I've already done, but what I'm saying is that when that vc is presented, the video freezes, and the audio continues playing.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with your AVPlayerLayer. Can you please post the code.